# Jersey: Pure Dependency Injection and global (singleton) objects

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey, jersey-2.0

I have just started my first Java REST project using Jersey.

In this project, I will implement Pure Dependency Injection architectural pattern (aka Poor Man's Dependency Injection).

If I understand correctly, a new instance of this class will be created for each incoming HTTP request:

```
@Path("/v1")
public class ApiControllerV1 {

    @POST
    @Path("/measurements")
    public String newMeasurement() {
        // some code here
    }
}
```

I could "tie" the life-cycle of Composition Root to the life-cycle of `ApiControllerV1`, but then I'm loosing ability to share objects between different requests.

Therefore, I need to find some "global" object to which I can "tie" the Composition Root. This "global" object should be accessible from `ApiControllerV1`. I'm sure that such an object exists, but I couldn't find it until now. Please point me in the right direction (code snippets will be greatly appreciated).

Comment: Why don't you just pass it to the constructor? You can register _instances_ of your controller with the ResourceConfig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register instance of your controllers. This way you can just pass whatever you want through the constructor. Per request instantiation is only the default, if you register by class or allow Jersey to package scan for your controllers. But this is not mandatory

```
public class AppConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public AppConfig() {
        final Whatever whatever = new Whatever();
        register(new Controller1(whatever));
        register(new Controller2(whatever));
    }
}
```

If you are using a web.xml for configuration, you can configure the `AppConfig` to be used by doing

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.AppConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Previously, you might've had something like

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.your.packages</param-value>
</init-param>
```

which allows Jersey to scan for your resources and register them for you. You can get rid of this because now we are registering everything ourselves in the `AppConfig`.

Anything else you need to configure with Jersey, you can do inside the `AppConfig`. See the [API for ResourceConfig](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.22.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html)

As an aside, you should look into using the DI system provided already by Jersey. It's pretty easy to use.

Comment: I'm sure that standard DI container is easy to use, but I want to implement Pure DI due to other reasons. So, if I do it like this, there will be just one instance of `ApiControllerV1` shared between requests, but its methods would still be called on different threads, right? I just want to make sure that I don't accidentally reduce my backend to single threaded...

Comment: Yeah, that's how it works. As long as the controller is stateless or thread-safe, you should be OK

Comment: @jwells131313 I assumed the OP meant Manually injecting dependencies as opposed to Inversion of Control